# Creating Variable in Expect Script using Sysname

Tags: expect

I'm trying to create an expect script that can automatically back up the config files of our Extreme switches. I need each config file to have a unique name so I can tell them apart and I'd like to use the sysname for this. On Extreme switches the sysname shows on each line in the following format:

ITSwitch.1 #

ITSwitch.2 #

All I need to know is how to capture all characters before the '.' so I can set it as a variable and use that to create the new config files before I upload them to our tftp server. I'm only recently getting into expect scripting but this seems like something easy that I'm just missing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not as easy as you'd hope. On the remote system, just hit Enter to show a new prompt, and regex-match the prompt to extract the sysname:

```
send "\r"
expect -re {\r\n([^.]+).* # ?$}
set sysname $expect_out(1,string)
```

---

Plan B: assuming there is no whitespace in the sysname:

```
send "show switch\r"
expect -re {
    {Sysname: (\S+)} { set sysname $expect_out(1,string) }
    {# ?$}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, this is getting me closer but it's not grabbing what I expected it to grab. I think I could reverse engineer what you have though and make it work if I knew what these commands are doing in that line of code. Would you be able to explain it to me a little?

Comment: Expect manual: https://manpage.me/?q=expect. Expect is an extension of the Tcl language. Documentation is here: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm

Comment: What parts of that code are troubling you? The regular expression?

Comment: I guess the problem is I understand pretty much what it should do but expect isn't grabbing the sysname and instead is just outputting blank space. So my next thought process was to run 'show switch'. If I do that, I get something like this for the first line.... 'sysName:                    ITSwitch'. I've altered your code so I can grab the word sysname, albeit there's still an extra empty line and then the word sysname shows up. So i guess now I'm looking to skip the first word in a line and grab the second word which should be the ITSwitch output

Comment: I'll go through the manuals though, I'm new to this so I guess I really should finish doing research on expect before I start diving too deep.

Comment: Alright, if I add send "show switch\r" to my code the switch will give me lines of information. The first line is 'Sysname: ITSwitch'. What command would I use to create ITSwitch as a variable in this scenario? I think your previous solution is correct but something weird is preventing expect from seeing the sysname this way so plan B looks to be the safer option here.

Comment: plan B added. Let me know if it works. Also, while you're working on the expect code, add the command `exp_internal 1` -- that will turn on verbose debug output so you can see how the patterns are/aren't matching.

Comment: Thank you for your help Glenn. Your first code worked after I tried it with the exp_internal 1 on so I could backtrack what was happening. The error was on my side of course but I was able to resolve it and run the program with the correct results.